# Is it not possible to store BigDecimal values in a single-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, precision, bigdecimal

My goal is store BigDecimal values as I input them through the Scanner class. I want to store BigDecimal numbers into an array so that I can sort them numerically. Can this be done using a single-dimensional array?

I can't find any BigInteger methods designed for this task. I want BigDecimal values because the decimal precision is important to me.

Comment: `new BigDecimal[size];`

Comment: Would this not be an array containing BigDecimals? As such there would not need to be specific methods within BigDecimal to deal with this

Comment: You're both right. This works: BigDecimal[] arrayValue = new BigDecimal[n];

I guess I forgot to include the array size. That confused me. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort them easily, you could do the following:

```
    BigDecimal x1 = new BigDecimal("1235.2345");
    BigDecimal x2 = new BigDecimal("235.2345");
    BigDecimal[] nums = {x1,x2};
    List<BigDecimal> lnums = Arrays.asList(nums);
    Collections.sort(lnums);
```

`Arrays.asList()` merely passes the value of the reference of your array.  `Collections.sort()` uses merge sort.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you,

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(5.94839);
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal(9.03937);
BigDecimal[] myBDArr = {x,y};
System.out.println(myBDArr[0]);
System.out.println(myBDArr[1]);
```

**Output:**

```
5.948389999999999844249032321386039257049560546875
9.0393699999999999050714905024506151676177978515625
```